# ERROR: FILENAME.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: python, amazon-ec2

I am using a AWS EC2 vistual server running redhat linux  I have a problem installing whl files whenever i try installing one i keep getting this error

````
ERROR: mysqlclient-2.2.0-pp39-pypy39_pp73-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.```
````

I am using python version: 3.9.16

```
pip version: pip 21.3.1 from /usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)
```

I think I've tried everything. someone told me that the file is for windoews if so where can i download the whl files for linux

Comment: Those are wrong wheels, you are trying to install PyPy wheels into CPython. Also that wheel is for *windows*, not linux.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `.whl` file of `mysqlclient` for Linux. You will have to build it from source:

From the [PyPI page](https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/):

```
sudo yum install python3-devel mysql-devel
```

then

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

Comment: when I do pip install mysqlclient i get this error: ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
Failed to build mysqlclient
ERROR: Could not build wheels for mysqlclient, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Comment: Please post whole error message with full traceback. I also suggest you to post a new question as this error has nothing to do with your original question.